# Nuxt/axios gives net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error on some postrequests

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using Laravel as backend and Nuxt as front. i get `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error in some of my post request. as i `console.log()` my `axios` found out the error is on request not response.
this is my code:

note: i'm in my cms and gonna insert/edit my product's title, model and description. if my `pId` is filled (i'm on edit) i send this data for example:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title: ".....",
  "model": "....",
  "text": "...."
}
```

but if the pId is empty, i go for inser without `id` in my data.
the axios url is same, on my back i check for `id` if there is not so it's create.

it works on create (without id) but gives me the error when send my request with id for edit.
BTW i tested it on `postman` and it's working!!

Oh and some other note!! if u see some `this` and don't find the reference, it's because i added them globally as mixins, like `this.editProduct.pId` that is a mapGetters.

```
<template>
<div class="pt-6">
    <v-row class="ma-0">
    <v-col cols="12" md="12" class="pa-0">
        <v-row class="ma-0">
        <!-- form 1 -->
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6" class="px-1 text_details_color3">
            <v-text-field :label="lang.title" outlined v-model="description.title" @change="changed('desc')" ></v-text-field>
        </v-col> 
        <!-- form 2 --> 
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6" class="px-1"> 
            <v-text-field :label="lang.model" outlined v-model="description.model" @change="changed('desc')"></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <!-- form 4 -->
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12" class="px-1">
            <v-textarea :label="lang.description" outlined rows="3" auto-grow v-model="description.text" @change="changed('desc')"></v-textarea>
        </v-col>
        <!-- btn -->
            <addproductbtn :section="section" :disabledbtn="disabledBtn" />
        </v-row>
    </v-col>
    </v-row>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import addproductbtn from '~/components/global/cms/addproductbtn'
export default {
    components:{
        'addproductbtn': addproductbtn
    },
    props:['err'],
    data () {
      return {
        description:{
            title: null,
            model: null,
            text: null,
        },
        pId: null,
        descChange: false,
        section: 'desc',
        disabledBtn: true
      }
    },

    methods: {
        async insertData(){
            let withOutErr = true
            if(this.notEmpty(this.description.title) && this.notEmpty(this.description.model) && this.descChange){
                if(this.notEmpty(this.pId)){
                    let response = await this.axiosPost('product/details', {
                        "pId": this.pId,
                        "title": this.description.title,
                        "model": this.description.model,
                        "text": this.description.text
                    })
                    if(this.resOk(response.status)){
                        this.descChange = false
                        this.setEditProductDesc({
                            title: this.description.title,
                            model: this.description.model,
                            text: this.description.text,
                        })
                    }else{
                        withOutErr = false
                    }
                }else{
                    let response = await this.axiosPost('product/details', {
                        "title": this.description.title,
                        "model": this.description.model,
                        "text": this.description.text
                    })
                    if(this.resOk(response.status)){
                        this.pId = response.data.pid
                        this.descChange = false
                        this.setEditProductId(this.pId)
                        this.setEditProductDesc({
                            title: this.description.title,
                            model: this.description.model,
                            text: this.description.text,
                        })
                    }else{
                        withOutErr = false
                    }
                }
            }
            return withOutErr
        },
        changed(){
            this.descChange = true
            this.enableBtn()
        },
        enableBtn(){
            if(this.description.title && this.description.model){
                this.disabledBtn = false
            }
        }
    },

    created(){
        this.description.title = this.editProduct.description.title
        this.description.model = this.editProduct.description.model
        this.description.text = this.editProduct.description.text
        this.pId = this.editProduct.pId
        
        this.enableBtn()

        this.$nuxt.$on('insert', (section)=>{
            if(section === this.section){
                if(this.insertData()){
                    this.goTo('cms/product')
                }
            }
        })
        this.$nuxt.$on('nextbtn', (section)=>{
            if(section === this.section){
                if(this.insertData()){
                    $nuxt.$emit('nextpanel')
                }
            }
        })
    },

  }
</script>
```

Comment: The issue i directly see is that `insertData` is async and so in your two event handles set inside `created` you should `await` for it.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli now that u mentioned, i was trying to get the `insertData` return and if it was true do the things in my event listeners. but did'nt work. how should do it? and i dont think it's because of this! i used the same for other fields like price. but they r all on edit (get `pId`)

Comment: change `(section)=>{` to `async (section)=>{` and the `if(this.insertData()){` to `if(await this.insertData()){`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli still get net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: the issue is most likely on the backend. What goes on in the `product/details` endpoint ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it's not backend, if so postman should have given error too. on my back i check, if there is no `pId` create a new record in my DB and return pId in response body. if there is `pId` update the record and return an empty response body with a _msg in header. oh BTW i can't access my custom header (_msg) too!! know anything?

Comment: What if the pId is wrong ? check your network tab in your browser's dev tools and see what gets send, and if it is the right type (integer/no quotes, string/quotes)